# Check if data exists in Django annotate queryset

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

***Environments***

- Django 2.0
- DRF 3.11
- mariaDB

I want to output'N' if at least one of the columns is 0, and'Y' if all of them are 1.

---

***Database***
[image: database example]

---

***Model***

```py
class UserPoint:
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', others options)
    poinit = models.IntegerField()
    used = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    deleted = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

---

***Expected results***

- total_point_used : Sum of points where used is 1
- used_status : 'N' if any of used has 0 or 'Y' if all values ​​of used are 1

| user | username | total_point_used | used_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'AA' | 600 | 'N' |
| 2 | 'BB' | 0 | 'N' |
| 3 | 'CC' | 500 | 'Y' |

---

***Tried queryset***

```py
q = UserPoint.objects.filter(
    deleted=0
).values(

    username=F('user__username')
    .... others values ....

).annotate(
    
    total_point_used=Sum(  # Sum of used point
                Case(
                    When(
                        used=1,
                        then='point',
                    ), output_field=IntegerField(),
                )
            ),

    # I don't know what to do with used_status.
    # tried <- not work
    #used_status=Case(
    #                When(
    #                    used=1,
    #                    then=Value('Y')
    #                ),
    #            default=Value('N'),
    #            output_field=CharField()
    #        )

    # I want something like this.
    used_status=Exists(used=0, then='N', default='Y')
)
```

---

How can I get the value I expect in annotate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can use [`Sum` with filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations):

```
from django.db.models import Q, Case, When, Sum

# rest of the code
.annotate(
    total_point_used=Sum('point', filter=Q(used=1)),
    used_status=Case(
                    When(
                        used=1,
                        then=Value('Y')
                    ),
                default=Value('N'),
                output_field=CharField()
            )
)
```